# Função similar a indexOf() em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Supondo que eu tenho uma string:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget leo consectetur, condimentum est eu, convallis dolor. Aliquam fringilla et odio a congue. Phasellus accumsan, velit in elementum porttitor, massa mi tristique velit, non molestie tellus nisl et odio. Sed id orci mollis ex egestas semper. Cras diam purus, viverra a arcu non, placerat suscipit sapien. Sed suscipit tincidunt urna, in accumsan lacus suscipit a. Suspendisse ut imperdiet urna, a ultricies ex. Vivamus eu pellentesque risus, vitae suscipit odio. Nam enim leo, auctor nec molestie non, gravida vel felis..."

E queira varrer essa string usando um array de strings para saber quais "matchs" encontro nela, como posso fazer de uma maneira mais performática do que utilizando o

```
indexOf()
```

segue exemplo do meu código:

```
var strErro = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget leo consectetur, condimentum est eu, convallis dolor. Aliquam fringilla et odio a congue. Phasellus accumsan, velit in elementum porttitor, massa mi tristique velit, non molestie tellus nisl et odio. Sed id orci mollis ex egestas semper. Cras diam purus, viverra a arcu non, placerat suscipit sapien. Sed suscipit tincidunt urna, in accumsan lacus suscipit a. Suspendisse ut imperdiet urna, a ultricies ex. Vivamus eu pellentesque risus, vitae suscipit odio. Nam enim leo, auctor nec molestie non, gravida vel felis. In pharetra dolor urna, at mattis lectus finibus in. Praesent sed facilisis diam. Pellentesque ornare luctus placerat. Aenean nisl augue, hendrerit ac metus id, fringilla tempor eros. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque feugiat, augue vitae cursus scelerisque, libero sem pellentesque neque, non vehicula urna urna vel justo. Curabitur fringilla finibus fringilla. Curabitur fermentum eros vel massa hendrerit euismod. Curabitur scelerisque ipsum a est egestas, accumsan elementum augue interdum. Duis ex turpis, placerat non tincidunt tincidunt, viverra at lorem. Proin sapien nisi, semper in velit quis, egestas placerat eros. Pellentesque non felis auctor massa rhoncus auctor. Aenean feugiat suscipit ex, eu porttitor neque vestibulum nec. Donec sollicitudin euismod vestibulum. Proin varius, ex ac dignissim cursus, enim ex convallis quam, vel porta ante nisl tempor dui. Pellentesque vel facilisis velit, eget pharetra velit. Nulla fermentum vel turpis vel rutrum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer mattis metus auctor, volutpat justo sed, porta ante. Donec tincidunt rhoncus urna non finibus. Pellentesque ut venenatis nisi. Praesent bibendum est id sapien consequat, a molestie tellus sollicitudin. Donec nec ligula at est lacinia finibus ac id diam. Praesent efficitur diam eu diam porttitor, quis ullamcorper justo consectetur. Suspendisse lectus enim, ornare venenatis ipsum ac, efficitur sollicitudin enim. Sed at enim tempus, vestibulum arcu et, scelerisque dui. Etiam eu malesuada eros, nec rutrum justo. Cras a odio maximus, tristique nisl at, ullamcorper nibh. Nunc quis interdum magna. Ut et eros ac ligula tristique sodales et iaculis justo. Sed aliquet nulla vitae leo scelerisque, non lacinia odio efficitur. Aliquam mauris magna, dictum nec mauris et, congue viverra ligula. Aliquam vestibulum ligula in augue venenatis viverra. Pellentesque in urna at nulla placerat consectetur a eu arcu. Fusce augue mauris, suscipit vel libero eu, vulputate iaculis nunc. Aenean condimentum neque quis urna egestas, ut feugiat ex efficitur. Morbi vitae ante erat. Fusce pretium quam vel purus maximus, ut rutrum mi volutpat. Cras pellentesque aliquam justo, ut maximus lorem consectetur sit amet. Sed nec leo sed magna scelerisque euismod at eget urna.";


var erros = "";
var found = false;
var ini;
var erro = ["erro1", "erro2", "erro3", "tempor"];

for (var i=0; i<erro.length;i++){

    ini = strErro.indexOf(erro[i]);   

    if (ini!=-1 && found){
        erros+= erro[i]+" ";
    } else if (ini!=-1) {
        erros+= erro[i]+" ";
        found=true;
    }

}

if (!found) {
    strErro;
} else {
    erros;
}
```

Comment: @Rafael Acioly Obrigado pela ajuda a manter o post mais organizado e limpo!

Comment: E qual é o problema? A função `indexOf` já não resolve seu caso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira  mais performática.

Comment: Nesta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/1452488) do SOen há 6 maneiras de se fazer e um [teste](http://jsben.ch/#/RVYk7) entre as mesmas que conclui que o `indexOf` é a maneira mais rápida (para esta situação).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss No meu teste o "regex"* foi o mais performático, mas acredito que o ganho não seja tão grande.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/xm2BV Na maioria dos testes o indexOf acaba sendo mais rápido do que loops tradicionais

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> E queira varrer essa string usando um array de strings para saber quais "matchs" encontro nela, como posso fazer de uma maneira mais performática do que utilizando o indexOf()

No caso o `indexOf` esta bom da maneira que esta, a unica coisa que eu faria para melhorar (é apenas micro-otimização) seria salvar o valor total e reduzir uma das ifs:

```
for (var i = 0, j = erro.length, current; i < j; i++) {

    current = erro[i];

    if (strErro.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
        erros+= current+" ";
    }
}

found = erros !== ""; //Equivale ao true
```

Claro que salvar valores de arrays em uma variável (`current`) e o total de `.length` só é significante se a `var erro` for gigante. A parte do 2 ifs não tinha muito sentido, pois `found=true` será executado apenas uma vez

### Um adendo

Se for para usar o `.some` creio que o regex é totalmente dispensável, poderia simplesmente fazer assim:

```
erro.some(function(current) {
    if (strErro.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
        erros += current;
    }
});
```

Comment: A var erro contém aproximadamente 90 Strings no momento, mas ela cresce no dia a dia.

Comment: Foi o que eu imagine @Tiaurls, por isto fiz salvar o `.length` na `j`

Answer (score 5):

[Benchmark](http://jsben.ch/#/jVXVQ) das funções propostas, caso surjam mais, eu atualizo.

## Chrome Versão 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Firefox Versão 51.0 (32-bit)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Opera Versão 43.0.2442.1144 (64-bit)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O q mostra q se quer performance mesmo tem até que fazer versão diferente para cada navegador. E monitorar se continua sendo verdade.

Comment: O motor JS do Firefox tem otimização interna, o resultado dele é o unico que varia e geralmente é mais rapido que outros motores, mas não é tudo que ele consegue "pré-otimizar". Esta otimização geralmente ocorre se estiver em funções, agora note a diferença se fizer assim: http://jsben.ch/#/rKfMX

Comment: Muito bom, ótimo teste! Interessante como o motor de cada navegador implementa e processa diferente os mesmos comandos!

Answer (score 0):

Não tem problema de usar o `indexOf`, porém existe uma maneira de deixar o código mais limpo usando `array map`

```
var strErro = "teste teste teste";
var erros = "";
var erro = ["erro1", "erro2", "erro3", "tempor"];

erro.map(function(value){
   if(strErro.indexOf(value) > -1){
      erros+= value+" ";
   }
});

if (erros.length > 0) {   
    erros;
} else {
    strErro;
}
```

Comment: obrigado, teria alguma fonte para eu entender melhor como funciona o array map ?

Comment: @Tiaurls Claro. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: O que piora a performance, que é o oposto do que deseja.

Comment: @bigown Pq piora?

Comment: Porque é uma abstração, cria uma indireção. Se a performance é necessária não se deve adotar o estilo funcional a não ser que a linguagem consiga otimizar isto, que não é o caso do JS.

Comment: @Matheus Obrigado pela referência.
Quando rodei o script aqui, aparentemente ele ficou um pouco mais lento mesmo, porém achei interessante o conceito que me foi apresentado a partir do map.

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ser feito usando `array.some` (mais informação aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

O método `some` irá percorrer todos os itens do array, dai podemos usar os valor como *regular expression* para facilitar a comparação:

```
var strErro = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget leo consectetur, condimentum est eu, convallis dolor. Aliquam fringilla et odio a congue. Phasellus accumsan, velit in elementum porttitor, massa mi tristique velit, non molestie tellus nisl et odio. Sed id orci mollis ex egestas semper. Cras diam purus, viverra a arcu non, placerat suscipit sapien. Sed suscipit tincidunt urna, in accumsan lacus suscipit a. Suspendisse ut imperdiet urna, a ultricies ex. Vivamus eu pellentesque risus, vitae suscipit odio. Nam enim leo, auctor nec molestie non, gravida vel felis. In pharetra dolor urna, at mattis lectus finibus in. Praesent sed facilisis diam. Pellentesque ornare luctus placerat. Aenean nisl augue, hendrerit ac metus id, fringilla tempor eros. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque feugiat, augue vitae cursus scelerisque, libero sem pellentesque neque, non vehicula urna urna vel justo. Curabitur fringilla finibus fringilla. Curabitur fermentum eros vel massa hendrerit euismod. Curabitur scelerisque ipsum a est egestas, accumsan elementum augue interdum. Duis ex turpis, placerat non tincidunt tincidunt, viverra at lorem. Proin sapien nisi, semper in velit quis, egestas placerat eros. Pellentesque non felis auctor massa rhoncus auctor. Aenean feugiat suscipit ex, eu porttitor neque vestibulum nec. Donec sollicitudin euismod vestibulum. Proin varius, ex ac dignissim cursus, enim ex convallis quam, vel porta ante nisl tempor dui. Pellentesque vel facilisis velit, eget pharetra velit. Nulla fermentum vel turpis vel rutrum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer mattis metus auctor, volutpat justo sed, porta ante. Donec tincidunt rhoncus urna non finibus. Pellentesque ut venenatis nisi. Praesent bibendum est id sapien consequat, a molestie tellus sollicitudin. Donec nec ligula at est lacinia finibus ac id diam. Praesent efficitur diam eu diam porttitor, quis ullamcorper justo consectetur. Suspendisse lectus enim, ornare venenatis ipsum ac, efficitur sollicitudin enim. Sed at enim tempus, vestibulum arcu et, scelerisque dui. Etiam eu malesuada eros, nec rutrum justo. Cras a odio maximus, tristique nisl at, ullamcorper nibh. Nunc quis interdum magna. Ut et eros ac ligula tristique sodales et iaculis justo. Sed aliquet nulla vitae leo scelerisque, non lacinia odio efficitur. Aliquam mauris magna, dictum nec mauris et, congue viverra ligula. Aliquam vestibulum ligula in augue venenatis viverra. Pellentesque in urna at nulla placerat consectetur a eu arcu. Fusce augue mauris, suscipit vel libero eu, vulputate iaculis nunc. Aenean condimentum neque quis urna egestas, ut feugiat ex efficitur. Morbi vitae ante erat. Fusce pretium quam vel purus maximus, ut rutrum mi volutpat. Cras pellentesque aliquam justo, ut maximus lorem consectetur sit amet. Sed nec leo sed magna scelerisque euismod at eget urna.";

var erros="";
// usadas barras para deixar as strings prontas para serem comparadas com regex
var regexList = [/erro1/, /erro2/, /erro3/, /tempor/];
// verifica os itens do array    
var isMatch = regexList.some(function(rx) { 
  var test = rx.test(strErro);
  if (test) {
    erros += rx.toString().replace('/','').replace('/',' ');
  }
    return; 
});


console.log('erros=' + erros)
```

O método *some* executa bem rápido, e a comparação com *regex* também.
Aqui você pode ver um *bechmark* comparando o uso de `for` e `some` e comparar a performance: https://jsperf.com/array-some-vs-loop

Comment: Chegou fazer teste pra ver se é mais rápido mesmo? Pode até ser, mas não sei. O requisito fundamental que ele quer é ser mais rápido.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar uma alternativa, mas do modo que estava implementado antes me pareceu mais veloz.

Comment: @Tiaurls e @bigown, eu testei os dois e me pareceu a mesma coisa realmente não percebi uma diferença de velocidade. Olhando o link que postei, no teste o *loop* usando `some` só se mostrou mais rápido quando a quantidade de itens a compara é maior.